# How to use sunspot_rails gem to search for related articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a mini blog app and i would like user to view articles that relates to what they are reading in the article show page. without the sunspot_rails gem i would do something like this

in my model

```
  def self.related_search(query, join = "AND")
    find(:all, :conditions => related_search_conditions(query, join))
  end

  def self.related_search_conditions(query, join)
    query.split(/\s+/).map do |word|
      '(' + %w[name description notes].map { |col| "#{col} LIKE #{sanitize('%' + word.to_s + '%')}" }.join(' OR ') + ')'
    end.join(" #{join} ")
  end
```

then in my view it would be like this

```
@article.related_search
```

but i want to use the sunspot_rails gem to make this way easy. Any help. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the `sunspot_rails` gem documentation? It is almost a trivial task.

Comment: this is so easy with thinkingshipnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RocketR mentions, this is a trivial use case for Sunspot.

First, use Sunspot to specify that you have three fields to be indexed as text.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :description
    text :notes
  end
end
```

Then issue a search, likely from within a controller action. The `@search` object below contains metadata about the search response, including the matching objects under its `results` method.

```
@search = Article.search do
  keywords query
end
@results = @search.results
```

To find other documents that are similar to an object you already have loaded, say in a `show` action, you can call the `more_like_this` instance method. This is a special kind of search, which uses Solr's "More Like This" functionality, and which returns a search object similar to the above full-text search. You can use its `results` method to render the results of that search.

```
<%= render @article.more_like_this.results %>
```

The [more_like_this](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/sunspot.rb#L373) method also accepts a block with similar options to the search block, so you can have more control over how you're judging similarity.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would try it out but before that would this bring out the result for my show action due to the fact that i have `@article = Article.find(:id)` and display the related articles that matches this one

Comment: I see, of course. Updated to add a basic example of `more_like_this` in Sunspot.

Comment: very interesting, does this mean that the `more_like_this` is a helper in sunspot?