# Related Articles In Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, related-content

I am trying to implement a related article on the user current page. I am not using sunspot or anything like that. I have tried this code by Uchenna Okafor but i get an error.

In the model i have

```
    #Related Search
def self.related_search(query, join = "AND")
    find(:all, :conditions => related_search_conditions(query, join))
end

def self.related_search_conditions(query, join)
    query.split(/\s+/).map do |word|
      '(' + %w[name instructions].map { |col| "#{col} LIKE #{sanitize('%' + word.to_s + '%')}" }.join(' OR ') + ')'
    end.join(" #{join} ")
end
```

On the show.html.erb i have

```
  <%= @recipe.related_search %>
```

My error message is

```
NoMethodError in Recipes#show

Showing /Users/sigidis/Ruby/food/app/views/recipes/show.html.erb where line #129 raised:

undefined method `related_search' for #<Recipe:0x10d4980a0>

Extracted source (around line #129):

126: <hr />
127: 
128: 
129:   <%= @recipe.related_search %>
130: 
131: 
132: <hr />

Rails.root: /Users/sigidis/Ruby/food
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:129:in `_app_views_recipes_show_html_erb__699416749_2260079280_0'
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:82:in `show'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"35"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Can someone help me out, I am new to Rails and i would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

References. [http://stackoverflow.com/q/7086092/812668][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be confusing an instance method with a class method. I don't know how you are creating `@recipe` , but try removing the `self` in `self.related_search` and `self.related_search_conditions`.

EDIT:

Ok, I think I understand a bit more. First, I'm assuming those methods are in your `recipe.rb` model and you have surrounded them with a `class Recipe` and `end`. Second, `@recipe` has no definition. So use `Recipe` instead to refer to the class. Lastly, your methods require at least the first argument to be passed, in this case the search query. So try the following: `Recipe.related_search("QUERY HERE")`.

Comment: i still get the same error. Do i need to declare anything in my controller as well?

Comment: Please check my edits and see if that answers your questions.

Comment: i think i understand a little what you mean. I have a controller called recipe.rb, that's where the above code is. I am trying to show recipes similar to the current one. I have tried your approach and i get 'ArgumentError in Recipes#show

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #129):

126: <hr />
129:   <%= Recipe.related_search %>
132: <hr />


app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:129:in `related_search'
app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:129:in `_app_views_recipes_show_html_erb__699416749_2189106480_0'
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:90:in `show'
'

Comment: recipe.rb is a model, should be separate from recipes_controller which is your controller. <%= Recipe.related_search %> will not work because you need to provide the first argument in that method. Like this: <%= Recipe.related_search('search term here') %>