# Is there any plugins to show related links with respectie of content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, related-content

Is there any plugins to find the realted links related to the content.

For example in our stack oveflow the question page shows the related questions.

I just want to make like this for my content how to do it.

Please suggest any plugins or gems available or please guide me how to do it if plugins not available.

Now am using Ruby(1.9.2) and Rails(2.3.9)

Thanks in Advance,

Ramanavel Selvaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which kind of related content you want to show, you can find several plugins and code (ex: for simple content sites to select related articles). Here is one:

[How to use sunspot_rails gem to search for related articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086092/how-to-use-sunspot-rails-gem-to-search-for-related-articles)

For more complex data, only you will know what related data correlates to it, so no magic plugin or gem can solve your problem there. (Ex: showing related products based on user behavior)

Comment: THanks alot the plugin having a method(more_like_this) for my requirement thanks for suggesting this.